# Action Bar Sherlock - Hide Actions on Collapse

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have three actions with the property SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS since I want to have the three of them always showing. However one of them has a collapse action view, and I wan't to hide the other two to have the full action bar for my layout when I click the action. Is there any way to do this?

This only seems to work if I use SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM but this way I only get two items on the action bar instead of three.

Comment: Can you provide a picture? you should be able to hide all icons as long as there is no overflow button.

Comment: Maybe you can use in the manifest android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" on your activity. Anyway more detail about your issu is needed to comprehend the issu ;)